# JQuery Insert Script & HTML into Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to insert a Script & HTML into an iframe. My issue is I can append the HTML to the iframe, but I cannot append it and also keep the source of the Iframe present.

The ultimate goal is to load HTML into the iframe source and have an overlay. Please advise.
I think I'm a little off on this one.

```
$(function() {
            var $frame = $('<iframe class="viewTrackingFrame" id="viewframe" src="https://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%" style="width:100%; height:100%;position:relative;">');
            $('body').html( $frame );
            setTimeout( function() {
                var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
                var $body = $('body',doc);
                $body.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
                $body.html('<div id="cursor" style="position:absolute;style:z-index:999999;"><img width="80" src="/assets/img/cursor_blue.png" /></div>');
                $body.html('<p id="test" style="z-index:9999999;">The queue length is: <span></span></p>');

            }, 1 );
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do.
Create an iframe with empty src attribute. Give it some id. Make a ajax call to required url to fetch all the html and append it to iframe's body. Now append any additional HTML that you wish to add in the same iframe. I have tested the method in a jsfiddle, check out http://jsfiddle.net/9vhL2/

```
$(function() {
    var $frame = $('<iframe class="viewTrackingFrame" id="viewframe" src="" width="100%" height="100%" style="width:100%; height:100%;position:relative;">');
            $('body').html( $frame );
                 var $body = $("#viewframe").contents().find('body');
            $.ajax( 
                {
                    url:"/echo/html/",
                    method:'POST',
                    success:function(data){
                      $body.append(data);
                      $body.append("<h1>Text added by script</h1>")
                      },
                    data: {html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p><h2>Text from page</h2>"}
                });
});
```

Comment: That's a good idea, can you make it work with adding the source to it after you've inserted the HTML? What would be an example with appending the src now to this also?